# SQL result dense Rank in revolving group pattern

Tags: sql, database, database-partitioning

Say I have a table like

| store | date | is_open |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bay | 1/1/2022 | true |
| Bay | 1/2/2022 | true |
| Bay | 1/3/2022 | true |
| Bay | 1/4/2022 | false |
| Bay | 1/5/2022 | false |
| Bay | 1/6/2022 | false |
| Bay | 1/7/2022 | true |
| Bay | 1/8/2022 | true |
| Bay | 1/9/2022 | true |
| Walmart | 1/7/2022 | true |
| Walmart | 1/8/2022 | false |
| Walmart | 1/9/2022 | true |

I want them to use partition by and get the rank of the group such as

| store | date | is_open | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bay | 1/1/2022 | true | 1 |
| Bay | 1/2/2022 | true | 1 |
| Bay | 1/3/2022 | true | 1 |
| Bay | 1/4/2022 | false | 2 |
| Bay | 1/5/2022 | false | 2 |
| Bay | 1/6/2022 | false | 2 |
| Bay | 1/7/2022 | true | 3 |
| Bay | 1/8/2022 | true | 3 |
| Bay | 1/9/2022 | true | 3 |
| Walmart | 1/7/2022 | true | 1 |
| Walmart | 1/8/2022 | false | 2 |
| Walmart | 1/9/2022 | true | 3 |

I started trying partition by `store` and `is_open` but really confuse what to use in order by clause any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LAG() to detect start of a group.

```
with cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, case when lag(is_open) OVER (PARTITION BY store ORDER BY date) = is_open then 0 else 1 end sflag
    FROM yourTable t
)
SELECT store, date, is_open, sum(sflag) over(PARTITION BY store ORDER BY date) grp
FROM cte
ORDER BY store, date;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1d4fdcc250d4904f1a152ef9a239572)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a gaps and islands problem.  One approach uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store ORDER BY date) rn1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store, is_open ORDER BY date) rn2
    FROM yourTable t
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.*, MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY store, is_open, rn1 - rn2) AS min_date
    FROM cte t
)

SELECT store, date, is_open,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY store ORDER BY rn1 - rn2, min_date) "group"
FROM cte2
ORDER BY store, date;
```

Note carefully that we use a second CTE `cte2` here to find the minimum date value for each island.  This is being done to distinguish two islands from different `is_open` values (true/false) which happen to have the same difference in row numbers.  It ensures that in the case of tie for difference in row number, the earlier island is reported first.

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo